# JqGrid Select Box in a cell

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, jqgrid, grid

I am trying to get a select box to be in a particular cell.  I have the checkboxes showing up just fine, but the select boxes are not being displayed.

```
 $('#list5').jqGrid({ 
  datatype: "local", 
  width: "100%",
  height: "100%",
  colNames:['Universe1','Connect String1', 'Report1', 'Object Type1','Path1','Owner1', '|', 'Universe', 'Select','Connect String', 'CheckBox', 'Report', 'Object Type','Path','Owner'], 
  colModel:[ 
   {name:'universe1', index:'universe1', width:70},{name:'connect1',index:'connect1', width:120}, 
        {name:'report1',index:'report1', width:90}, 
        {name:'objType1',index:'objType1', width:50, align:"right"}, 
        {name:'path1',index:'path1', width:50, align:"right"},
        {name:'owner1',index:'owner1', width:100, align:"right"},
        {name:'pipe',index:'pipe', width:10, align:"center"},
        {name:'universe', index:'universe', width:70}, 
        {name:'ship',index:'ship', width:90, editable: true, edittype:"select", formatoptions: {disabled : false}, editoptions:{value:"FE:FedEx;IN:InTime;TN:TNT;AR:ARAMEX"}},
        {name:'connect',index:'connect', width:120}, 
        { name: 'airPost', width: 40, index: 'airPost', formatter: 'checkbox', align: 'center', //Checkbox
                      editoptions: { value: "1:0" }, stype: 'select', editable:true, searchoptions: { value: "1:Yes;0:No" }, formatoptions: {disabled : false} },
        {name:'report',index:'report', width:90}, 
        {name:'objType',index:'objType', width:50, align:"right"}, 
        {name:'path',index:'path', width:50, align:"right"},
        {name:'owner',index:'owner', width:100, align:"right"}

       ], 

     caption: "Grid",
     autowidth: true,
     viewrecords: true,
     footerrow: true,
     userDataOnFooter: true,
     data: mydata
     });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably it is misunderstanding. You will see select box in cell only if the cell will be editing mode. For example you can include [cell editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing) support in your local jqGrid if you include two additional parameters in the grid definition

```
cellEdit: true,
cellsubmit: 'clientArray'
```

You can also use [inline editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing) instead.

I am not sure how your data in `mydata` array look like. It can be needed, that you have to add [formatter:'select'](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apredefined_formatter#formatter_type_select) additionally to the definition of the 'ship' column.

Comment: Thanks, I have been facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I got it working it was an issue with not having cellEdit, cellsubmit:, and editurl: added to the grid